# How do I do an on-click method on a button that directs to another component?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have two sign up components that contain forms, one for those signing up as individuals and one signing up as businesses, I have a main page component with two large buttons labeled, "Click here to sign up as an individual", "Click here to sign up as a business'. How do I link these components on Vue? I am hoping that upon click of the button the component renders on the same page and not a new tab.

Thanks in advance!

So far,

Attempted to configure the router.js(I have a feeling this might be where my issue is)
Added the routes to the v-button

App.vue

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-btn dark to="./components/CompanySignUp"> Sign up as a Company </v-btn>

    <v-btn dark to="./components/FreelanceSignUp"> Sign up as a Freelancer
    </v-btn>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",

  components: {},

  data: () => ({
    //
  })
};
</script>
```

router.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
import CommpanySignUp from "./components/CompanySignUp";
import FreelancerSignUp from "./components/FreelancerSignUp";

Vue.use(Router);

const router = new Router({
 mode: "history",
 base: process.env.BASE_URL,
 routes: [
   {
     path: "./components/CompanySignUp",
     name: "Company Sign Up",
     component: CommpanySignUp
   },
   {
     path: "./components/FreelancerSignUp",
     name: "Freelancer Sign Up",
     component: FreelancerSignUp
   }
 ]
});
```

main.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import vuetify from "./plugins/vuetify";
import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css'
import VueRouter from "vue-router";

Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

Comment: You should check for some tutorials or connect with me via my email(on my profile for lessons). But depending on what you're sending and receiving. So you can either decide to make use of props or use emitters ($emit) or eventbuses or vuex to store, set and get different states.

Comment: I have a few questions, but I'm happy to provide snippets. Do you want the registration components to be on a separate page (view) or within the same main page? Do you want the user to be able to navigate directly to the page if they have the correct url (mysite.com/register/business)?

Comment: @maestro.inc thank you! I will look into emit

Comment: @WesHarper thank you, I want the registration components to be on a separate view in the same window, so no new tab is opened and upon click the registration component is seen and nothing else

Comment: Okay great, I'll do a writeup. Did you use the vue-cli to create this project?

Comment: @WesHarper yes I believe I did!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good opportunity to use `vue-router`, but there are multiple approaches to this problem. Depending on scope, there may be more than one good answer. There is a comment above about using emitters and props, which is fine, but I would recommend using `vue-router` because it's made for this kind of dynamic component switching. If you've used the `vue-cli` it should be trivial to add, but the following example uses the standalone CDNs for brevity. This can all be done in separate files and the `vue-cli` will already have a nice scaffold for you if you want to see how that's done.

```js
const Main = {
      template: `
        <div>
          <router-link to="/register/business">Register for business</router-link>
          <router-link to="/register/personal">Register for personal</router-link>
        </div>
      `
    };

    const RegistrationPage = { template: '<router-view></router-view>' };
    const BusinessRegistration = {
      template: `
        <h1>Business</h1>
      `
    };
    const PersonalRegistration = {
      template: `
        <h1>Personal</h1>
      `
    };

    const routes = [
      {
        path: '/',
        component: Main
      },
      {
        path: '/register',
        component: RegistrationPage,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'business',
            component: BusinessRegistration
          },
          {
            path: 'personal',
            component: PersonalRegistration
          }
        ]
      }
    ];

    const router = new VueRouter({
      routes
    });

    const app = new Vue({
      router
    }).$mount('#app');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@2.0.0/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

There are multiple benefits to this approach:

1. Vue router is supported pretty well by the Vue community so you can find lots of documentation and examples.
2. Your end user can visit `mysite.com/register/business` and land on the correct page, rather than having to go through clicking on the button if they decide to leave your page and come back.
3. Much of the logic is abstracted away by the library rather than having to do complex conditional logic and event emitters.

This is a very simple example that relies heavily on the "getting started" docs [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#html). If you did start your project with the `vue-cli`, you should be able to run `vue add vue-router`, which should do some setup for you if you missed that step in the project creation process, otherwise you can use npm and set things up manually.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your vue router is already working and you already displayed your component What you did is already correct, just follow these steps to make it working.

**First** put a router view in your main app . like below

```
<v-app>
    <v-btn dark to="./components/CompanySignUp"> Sign up as a Company </v-btn>

    <v-btn dark to="./components/FreelanceSignUp"> Sign up as a Freelancer
    </v-btn>
    <router-view></router-view>
</v-app>
```

**Second** change your route name into this one, this route name will be use to call you component itself.

```
{
     path: "./components/CompanySignUp",
     name: "company_sign_up",
     component: CommpanySignUp
},
```

**Lastly** in your main, the final structrue is like this

```
<v-app>
        <v-btn dark to="{name:'company_sign_up'}"> Sign up as a Company </v-btn>

        <v-btn dark to="{name:'freelancer_sign_up'}"> Sign up as a Freelancer
        </v-btn>
        <router-view></router-view>
</v-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your `router.js` file defined correctly but you never included it in your app. Instead, you initialized another (empty) router in `main.js`. Just import your `router.js` and then include it in your initialization of the app.

```
import router from 'router.js'; <--- your file

new Vue({
  router,       <--------- apply router
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

The last thing left is to define a place for the router components to render. That is accomplished by placing a [`<router-view>`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-view) compenent somewhere in your app template.

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-btn dark to="./components/CompanySignUp"> Sign up as a Company </v-btn>
    <v-btn dark to="./components/FreelanceSignUp"> Sign up as a Freelancer
    </v-btn>

    <router-view></router-view>  <------------- component rendered here
  </v-app>
</template>
```

For maintenance reasons, consider using the `name` parameter for the [`:to`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#to) prop so you can minimize code changes if you ever need to update the path.